# Julia Graphs.jl ExVertex method not matching arguments

Tags: graph, julia, vertex

I am trying to create vertex and i found some example in Graphs.jl documentation but i can not figure out why it is not working.

```
using Graphs

V1 = ExVertex(1, "V1");
V1.attributes["size"] = 5.0
```

But it says that ExVertex has no method matching ExVertex(Int64, ASCIIString). Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

First let me check argument types of the `ExVertex()` function, using `?` command to get help:

```
help?> ExVertex
search: ExVertex

  No documentation found.

  Summary:

  type Graphs.ExVertex <: Any

  Fields:

  index      :: Int32
  label      :: UTF8String
  attributes :: Dict{UTF8String,Any}
```

So on my machine `index` must be `Int32`, now we will check the actual type of `1`: `typeof(1) # => Int32`, therefore if I call that function as you have called it ,I will get no error:

`V1 = ExVertex(1, "V1") # => vertex [1] "V1"`

This test raise another question: "Why type of number `1` is differ in our machines?"
To get the right answer we must check the Julia manual section about [integer types](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#integers):

> The default type for an integer literal depends on whether the target
>   system has a 32-bit architecture or a 64-bit architecture:
>
> `# 32-bit system: julia> typeof(1) Int32`
>
> `# 64-bit system: julia> typeof(1) Int64`
>
> The Julia internal variable WORD_SIZE indicates whether the target system is >32-bit or 64-bit.:
>
> `# 32-bit system: julia> WORD_SIZE 32`
>
> `# 64-bit system: julia> WORD_SIZE 64`

**Tip:** You can type cast `1` as `UInt32` like this:
`V1 = ExVertex(1%UInt32, "V1") # => vertex [1] "V1"`

Comment: I think that type of number is not problem. Later after i posted question i tried this `V1 = Graphs.ExVertex(1, "V1")` and it works. I think that it is not able to locate method ExVertex but I am not sure why because I am using other methods from package Graphs and they works.